# Change Full Calendar right header from button to list items

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar where I want to do the following things - please suggest the best way of doing so:

1. I want to re position the right header to the extreme left
2. Currently the header options are displayed as inline-block Buttons. I want
   them to be displayed as list items. The onclick functionality should
   not be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out myself:
to add a new button just need to added the following 
 
$('.fc-header-right').append('Some Button');

to align all the header right buttons to the left of the screen in a vertical list display format need to add styling to fullCalendar.css

```
.fc-header-right{
     position:absolute;
     left:0 ;
}
```

and add a class to the buttons and add styling to the class

```
.fc-header-right-button {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    padding: 0 .6em;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 1.9em;
    line-height: 1.9em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```